# Is the a more idiomatic (and hopefully elegant) way to compose a Scala Immutable Map of variable elements (length)?

Tags: scala

I have a need to compose elements along these lines

```
val aMap = Map("A" -> 1)
val bMap = if (b > -1) { aMap ++ Map("B" -> b) } else aMap
val cMap = if (!c.equals("")) { bMap ++ Map("C" -> c) } else bMap
```

Yes it should (and does) return `Map[String, Any]` by design -- unsure I can get more specific on the Any and since the data is scrubbed and converted to strings later on it's not a concern (at least for the purposes of this question)

Of course I would like to compose a singe map in one shot. Bear in mind that this is a simple case - there might be a much great number of elements in other use cases.

I'm trying not to break down and use mutable except as a last resort :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't anything that does that much better in the standard library, but you can enrich `Map` so that it can add keys conditionally. Something like this:

```
implicit class MapExt[A, B](m: Map[A, B]) {
    def withValueIf(condition: => Boolean)(kv: (A, Any)): Map[A, Any] =
        if(condition) m + kv else m
}
```

And use it like this:

```
 val b = -2
 val c = "abc"

 Map("A" -> 1)
     .withValueIf(b > -1)("B" -> b)
     .withValueIf(c.nonEmpty)("C" -> c)

 res28: Map[String,Any] = Map(A -> 1, C -> abc)
```

If you want to concatenate maps instead of single key-value pairs, then you would just change `kv: (A, Any)` to `kv: Map[A, Any]` and `m + kv` to `m ++ kv`. I actually prefer using this in a similar manner in some projects, because it avoids the need to re-write the `if(condition) m + kv else m` logic over and over.

And if anyone is interested in a version that does not use `Any`, but retains the original type:

```
implicit class MapExt[A, B](m: Map[A, B]) {
    def withValueIf[C <: B](condition: => Boolean)(kv: (A, C)): Map[A, B] =
        if(condition) m + kv else m
}

scala> Map("a" -> 1).withValueIf(b < 0)("B" -> b).withValueIf(c.nonEmpty)("C" -> -1)
res30: Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1, B -> -2, C -> -1)
```

And if you *really* don't want to use implicits, I would at least wrap the if/else logic within some method to avoid re-writing.

```
def cMap[A, B](condition: => Boolean)(m: Map[A, B]): Map[A, B] =
    if(condition) m else Map.empty

 Map("A" -> 1) ++
     cMap(b > -1)(Map("B" -> b)) ++
     cMap(c.nonEmpty)(Map("C" -> c))
```

Comment: +1: About the version for retaining the type, wouldn't something like `def withValueIf[C >: B](condition: => Boolean, kv: (A, C)): Map[A, C]` be more appropriate? In your version, I see that you can only add elements whose type is a subtype of the elements of the map, and as I see in the OP, he adds any kind of values, so, wouldn't it be better to try to conserve as much of the original type as possible?

Comment: @kaktusito I used `C <: B` since `Map` is covariant over the values. ie. to keep `Map[A, B]` and not return `Map[A, C]`. There are really so many variations of this depending on the use case. I suppose `C >: B` would be better for the OP, but I was just presenting it as another solution.

Answer (score 1):

In such situations I like to use an operator which takes some value (left operand) and some function (right operand) and applies that function on that value. Such operator is usually (e.g. in F#) called *pipe* and denoted as `|>`. Scala doesn't have it but it's easy to write:

```
implicit class piped[A](private val a: A) extends AnyVal {
  def |>[B](f: A => B): B = f(a)
}
```

Then, your example could look like this:

```
val theMap = Map("A" -> 1) |> 
 (m => if(b > -1) m ++ Map("B" -> b) else m) |>
 (m => if(c != "") m ++ Map("C" -> c) else m)
```

or

```
val theMap = Map("A" -> 1) |> 
 (if(b > -1) (_ ++ Map("B" -> b)) else identity) |>
 (if(c != "") (_ ++ Map("C" -> c)) else identity)
```

It's quite generic and relieves you from making up names for intermediate results.

Answer (score 1):

Without any additional methods, that would be something like this:

```
Map("A" -> 1) ++ 
  (if (b > -1) Map("B" -> b) else Map.empty)  ++
  (if (c != "") Map("C" -> c) else Map.empty) ++  
  // etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can use `+` to add `(String, Any)` pairs to the map instead of using `++` to merge maps:

```
Map("A" -> 1) + ("B" -> 2)
```

You can also use the `Map` constructor by passing in a whole sequence of `(String, Any)` pairs:

```
Map("A" -> 1, "B" -> 2)
```

So, if you can construct your sequence of pairs first, then you can do this more easily:

```
val mySequenceOfTuples = Seq("A" -> 1, "B" -> "foo")
Map(mySequenceOfTuples:_*)
//Or, equivalently
mySequenceOfTuples.toMap
```

So then you can construct the list of pairs in 1 expression, and construct the map right there:

```
Seq(
    Some("A" -> 1), 
    Some("B" -> b).filter(_._2 > -1),  
    Some("C" -> c).filterNot(_.isEmpty)
).flatten.toMap
```

Another approach is to construct the full map, and then filter:

```
Map("A" -> 1, "B" -> b, "C" -> c).filter { 
    case ("B", b) => b > -1 
    case ("C", c) => !c.isEmpty 
    //Keep all others in the default case
    case _ => true 
}
```

Finally, you can also use `++` along with the fact that merging an empty map is a no-op:

```
Map("A" -> b) ++ 
    (if(b > -1) Map("B" -> b) else Map.empty) ++ 
    (if(!c.isEmpty) Map("C" -> c) else Map.empty)
```

Comment: Yeah - I wandered down the filter path but decided against it as there were too many possibly ways to shoot myself in the foot if I didn't expect all edge cases and some of the inputs are user generated...

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like

```
val aMap = Map("A" -> 1)
def bMap(b: Int) = if (b > -1) Some("B" -> b) else None
def cMap(c: String) = if (c.nonEmpty) Some("C" -> c) else None
```

Then:

```
scala> aMap ++ bMap(1) ++ cMap("")
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any] = Map(A -> 1, B -> 1)
```